# equality of spectrums from 2 lemmas

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a $B^{*}$ algebra and let $B$ be a sub $B^{*}$ algebra. Deduce from the following 2 lemmas that for $x$ in $B$ we $x$ is invertible in $B$ iff it is invertible in $A$.

Lemma 1) Let $x$ in $A$ be self adjoint. Then, ${\sigma}_{A}(x)$ is real.

Lemma 2) $d({\sigma}_{B}(x))$ is a subset of $d({\sigma}_{A}(x))$ where $d$ is the boundary.

My attempt: It suffice to prove that if $x$ in B is invertible in $A$ it is invertible in $B$. Let $x$ be invertible in $A$. Then $x^{*}x$ is invertible in $A$ and self adjoint.  Assume for a contradiction that 0 is not in ${\sigma}_{B}(x^{*}x)$. By lemma 1) ${\sigma}_{A}(x^{*}x)$ is real. So by lemma 2) $d({\sigma}_{B}(x^{*}x))$ is real. Then I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you can assume at this point. Do you know at this point that $\sigma(x^{\star}x)\subseteq [0,\infty)$? Then you should be able to show what you want by looking at $r_{A}=\inf\sigma_{A}(x^{\star}x)$ and comparing this to $r_{B}=\inf\sigma_{B}(x^{\star}x)$ in order to conclude that $x^{\star}x$ is invertible in $B$. That gives you a left inverse for $x$ in $B$. Then repeat the argument using $xx^{\star}$ instead.